# Django 1.5 Management Command - IOError: [Errno 10] - No child processes

Tags: python, django

I've been executing a particular management command from an external application for the past 12 months without issue. I've recently upgraded to Django 1.5 and for some reason, it is now throwing:

```
IOError: [Errno 10] No child processes
```

Here is the management command:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '<camera_id camera_id ...>'
    help = 'Checks the alerts table once motion is detected'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for id in args:
            try:
                camera = IpCamera.objects.get(pk=id)
                #add log
                ipcl = IpCameraLog(ipCamera=camera, type='started').save()
                #check alerts                   

            except IpCamera.DoesNotExist:
                raise CommandError("Camera %s does not exist" % id)
```

Anyone have any ideas what would be causing this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i believe that with django 1.5 you should change the arg BaseCommand to NoArgsCommand

```
retry it like this:

from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
    class Command(NoArgsCommand):
       # whatever here
```

that works for me .

Comment: ok, make sure that you add the __init__.py file in the directory where is locate the file contening the class Command, that let django know it a python package

Comment: the management command runs fine outside of the external application that is calling it, it's only when it's inside the app that it fails when called :(